# Prime number generator in C

Tags: algorithm, c, primes

I have to print numbers between two limits `n` and `m`, `t` times.

I created `t` variable that stores a number of test cases.

Outer for loop iterates for every test cases.

Inner for loop prints primes from `m` to `n`.

## Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
int is_prime(int);
 
int main(void) {
    int t, m, n;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
        for (int j = m; j <= n; j++) {
            if (is_prime(j)) {
                printf("%d\n", j);
            }
        }
        if (i < t - 1) printf("\n");
    }
 
    return 0;
}
 
int is_prime(int num) {
    if (num <= 1) return 0;
    for (int i = 2; i * i <= num; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Problem: http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/

Can I have review?

Comment: You might be interested in a similar review I did a while back; a lot of the algorithmic notes there also apply here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/165576/codechef-prime-number-generator/165601#165601

Answer (score 1):

The only even prime number is two, so with a little extra coding you can ignore even numbers in the `for` loop.  For even more speed use a sieve, though maybe save that for when you get a 'TLE' failure.

A more formal code layout would be good as well, your `if` statements need expanding to include `{...}`.  More vertical space (blank lines) a well as explanatory comments help.  When you come back to your old code six months later you will thank yourself.

I prefer to set 0 and 1 as `FALSE` and `TRUE` to make code easier to read YMMV.

```
int is_prime(int num) {
  if (num <= 1) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  // Even numbers.
  if (num % 2 == 0) {
    return num == 2;  // 2 is the only even prime.
  }

  // Odd numbers.
  // Start loop at 3 and step 2 to skip even divisors.
  for (int i = 3; i * i <= num; i += 2) {
    if (num % i == 0) {
        return FALSE;
    }
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Just include `<stdbool.h>` to avoid having to define it yourself, and get the lowercase versions at the same time.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury: Thanks.  My C is *very* rusty.

Answer (score 1):

Good that OP's code handles values <= 0, yet could have used `is_prime(unsigned  num)` instead.  Further: this is a good place for the only even prime detect.

Corner concern: The `i * i <= num` test fails for large `num`, like `num = INT_MAX` as `i*i` is always <= than `INT_MAX` or it is `int` overflow - which is undefined behavior (UB).

Preference: Use `bool` for return values that are either 0 or 1.

Many modern compilers/processors calculate the remainder *and quotient* for little/no additional cost.  Use that as an exit condition.

```
bool is_prime(uintmax_t num) {
  if (num <= 3) {
    return num >= 2;
  }
  uintmax_t q = num;
  for (uintmax_t i = 3; i <= q; i += 2) {
    if (num % i == 0) {
      return false;
    }
    q = num / i;
  }
  return num%2;
}
```

The next step in prime detection is use of the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

---

Note for future: Code does not check the return value of `scanf()`.  This is OK for test code, but not for code under test.